# String method java assignment

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

So I'm having a bit of trouble on one of my assignments. I can't seem to figure out what I need to do. Here is the question:

Points for reading are assigned on the following basis: The first three books read are worth 10 points each. The next three books read are worth 15 points each. All books read over six are worth 20 points each. A student who reads 7 books would be awarded 95 points (30 for the first three plus 45 for the next 3 and 20 for the 7th book).

An external file contains a first and last name followed by an integer (the number of books read)

Print on each persons name, the number of books read and the points earned. The names should be in the order last, first with the only the last name in all capital letters. At the bottom of the list print out the average points for all readers and the winner of the contest.

Statements Required: input, output, decision making, loop control, strings

Data Location: prog700c.dat

Sample Output:

```
Reading Contest

Name        Books   Points

SUMMER Sam    4     45 

LAZY Linda    2     20

PRODDER Paul  5   60

MASTER K.C.   8    115

READER Richie 6  75

Average points per reader = 63.0
The winner of the contest is K.C. Master
```

The external file data is this:

```
SUMMER Sam   4

LAZY Linda   2

PRODDER Paul 5

MASTER K.C.  8

READER Richie 6
```

My current code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog505a
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Guest\\Documents\\java programs\\Prog700c\\Prog700c.in"));
    String data = kbReader.nextLine();
    while(kbReader.hasNextLine())
    {
```

I'm having a problem where I don't know what string method to use to only get the numbers from the external file to use them in the calculations. I know I can do the decision making, etc. but I just don't know what to do on this one part to get only the numbers from the external file. If someone could provide some direction or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to parse the String and extract the values you need. You can use regular expressions.

Comment: Integer#parseInt(String) should help. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: since you are using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) you could use its methods [hasNexInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) and [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) to get the parsed integers, for first and last name you could `hasNext` and `next`.

Comment: @A4L Yes, that's probably better than using `String.split()`, so I assimilated your comment into my answer :) Doesn't hurt for a new user to try both though.

Comment: @owlstead as a beginner one should try both ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.split("\\s+")` to split the line into three parts (check if they are three parts to be sure, print a warning and skip if not). This will return an array of strings. You can use `Integer.parseInt()` to read the number of books on the third item in the array (position 2, arrays in Java are "zero based").

Note that `"\\s+"` is a regular expression which finds 1 or more parts of whitespace. The strings within the whitespace and the beginning/end of the string are returned. If regular expressions are not allowed, try and find the index of the space-character within the string, and use `String.substring()` - and don't ignore the return value for string operations.

Alternatively you could use `next()`, `next()` and `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()` in your scanner.

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer? Please indicate what's missing or hit accept on my or Doroskevics answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to deliver what you're saying : 
Try to use something like:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

This way you would delete all non-digits in a string. After that you would need to parse the String to an integer or any other Number type.

Comment: This will work, but I'm not sure if this solution is a good solution. Imagine if a followup question would consist of lines containing `READER Dorosckevic(1) 4`...in other words, it does not scale.

Comment: i would create an extra string to hold that data and operate on that particular string.

Comment: It's great sideways thinking - which can be very important during programming - but sometimes it's the opposite of good problem decomposition. First splitting into separate elements seems the way to go...